# simple way to transfer massive database more than 50GB within short period

Tags: mysql

Have already scp from one server to another and dumped it as .sql file

the database is very big and is taking many days to import to the created mysql database from

the dump, using mysql -u root - p database name < .sql dump

which is the easiest way to import it please. more faster way

Comment: Use faster disks?

Comment: configure your server? - our 40GB sql takes only 45 minutes to import. you can also split the sql file for each table. there are many tools to download. then you can start more then 1 mysql import

Comment: @BerndBuffen does the mysql version of the source and destination determines? because the version of the source is is mysql 5.7 while destination is myql 8

Comment: and what about the processor speed of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Don't transfer the file separately.  Instead reach across the network:

If you are running the "load" on serverB and the dump is on serverB and loading serverA, do this on serverB

```
mysql -h serverA ... < dump.sql
```

It will still take a long time, but perhaps only have the time.